# How to improve the search filter performance after migrating access tables into sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, database-migration

Migrated the acces tables into sql server.After imported the migrated sql tables in my access VBA solution.in access default search filter is there.we can enable this by using options .

In that filter we can serach the data.in ms access it is working fine no performance issue,but for migrated tables the search option taking so much time.please help me out this performace issue.

Thanks,

Comment: You need to **AT LEAST** show us the table structure (columns and their datatypes), and **how you query** that table!!

Comment: Did you have indexes on your table in MS Access?  Then you need to recreate those same indexes in SQL Server if you have not already done so.